# How to delete only 56 from the below table?

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to SQL. From the below table I only want to delete 56 from the below rows.
Can someone point me with the SQL statement. Thanks in advance

```
Name                Product_ID
Product1            22,34,56,57,78
Product2            56,102,79
Product3            56,51,79
Product4            56,78,104
Product5            56,57,61
Product6            59,56,43
```

Comment: This is going to be difficult to do, which is why good database design does not build tables like yours. If you design bad tables with columns that contain multiple values (as you have), expect to have to jump through lots of hoops to do what should be very simple. You need a book or tutorial on how to properly design your tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
#For Delete
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE Product_ID=56;
#or
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE Product_ID LIKE '%56,%';
        
#If you want to remove the 56 from Product_ID
UPDATE tableName SET Product_ID= REPLACE(Product_ID, "56,","") WHERE Product_ID LIKE '%56,%';
```

**UPDATED:**
This should be simple if you have a good database design, but I'll try to help you with exactly what you need.

```
    UPDATE accnt_period_h SET period_name= REPLACE(TRIM(REPLACE( REPLACE( period_name , ",", " ") , "56","")), " ", ",") 
WHERE period_name LIKE '%56%';
```

Comment: what if 56 is the only id in value or last one?

Comment: Hi, I did update my answer

Comment: what if list contains id 556 or 566?